# Google Drive V3 with Java client library creates Untitled files on Android

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I have successfully migrated from V2 to V3 with my Android app. It works when I install it directly on the device via Android Studio, but when I install the APK manually or via Google Play Store, I get "Untitled" files for any create or upload, whether file or folder.

I use the Drive V3 API through the Java Client API Library https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/.

```
                GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
                    new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                            .requestEmail()
                            .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
                            .build();
            GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(mContext, signInOptions);
```

...

```
        Drive googleDriveService =
            new Drive.Builder(
                    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new GsonFactory(),
                    credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Foo bar")
                    .build();
```

...

```
    File folderMetaData = new File ()
            .setName("test")
            .setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder")
            .setParents(Collections.singletonList("root"));
    return mDriveService.files().create(folderMetaData)
            .setFields("id, name")
            .execute();
```

As I said, only changing the deployment from Android Studio install to a signed APK makes the create/upload not work any more. Any hints?

Comment: After long trial I found the error. Proguard was scrambling some reflection calls within the V3 API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding this to your proguard file should work:

```
   -keep class * extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson {
    *;
   }
   -keep class com.google.api.services.drive.** {
    *;
   }
```

Comment: Good finding! You save me a lot of time.